# Registrar IP de quienes modifican algo en mi sitio

Tags: php, sql-server

mi problema es el siguiente:

Tengo un sitio web donde al usuario se le da libertades de crear mas usuarios para su misma cuenta, modificar sus datos y eliminar registros que ya no desee (lo usual), se me pidió que creara un Log en la base de datos para llevar un registro de quienes visitan y hacen modificaciones, ya almaceno los datos necesarios pero me gustaría saber si existe una función para poder obtener la IP de quien esta haciendo la modificación.

De ante mano agradezco la ayuda y me disculpo si no esta bien formulada mi pregunta, gracias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Además de guardar la IP, te recomiendo almacenar el usuario actual que ejecuta la acción.

`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` contiene la IP desde donde se conecta. Digamos que esto es lo más 'confiable' que puedas encontrar.

Sin embargo, los usuarios pueden estar usando un servidor proxy, en este caso podrías definir `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']`,pero este valor puede ser facilmente falsificado. Por ejemplo, puede ser definido por alguien sin un proxy, o la IP puede ser una interna que viene desde un proxy.

Esto quiere decir que si vas a guardar `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']`, también guarda el valor `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` En ambos casos, guarda cada uno en un campo diferente.

Más información en: http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Perfecto!, muchas gracias me ha servido bastante, y si también guardo el usuario que esta haciendo los cambios pero quería guardar la ip solo por cuestiones de seguridad, gracias!

Comment: de nada hermano, estamos para servir, he publicado un enlace adicional en la respuesta, échale un ojo :D Por cierto si algo más hardcore quieres hacer, usando HTML5 puedes obtener la geolocalización del usuario hahaha, esto obligaría a cada usuario a aceptar primero que será 'vigilado' de cierta manera, lo dejo a tu criterio. Éxitos con el desarrollo y sigue participando de SOes :D

Comment: o vaya!, hahaha le daré una revisada a eso de la geolocalización seria muy bueno como propuesta de innovacion aquí y pues por la parte de la seguridad no creo que ningún usuario se moleste, gracias! :D

Comment: de nada! aquí te dejo un enlace de referencia: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_geolocation.htm